# Matter waves? what does de Broglie mean?

Tags: waves, matter

What is the physical meaning of somethings matter wave?

I mean its not like were all vibrations in spacetime, right?

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41892

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De Borglie said that wave nature exists for matter as it does for light.

The de Broglie wavelength is given by :

$\lambda=\frac{h}{P}$ , where h is planck's constant and P is the momentum of the particle.

In ordinary situations, de Broglie wavelength is very small and wave nature of matter can be ignored. To appreciate this point, let us calculate de Broglie wavelength of a $46gm$ golf ball moving with a speed of $30\frac{m}{s}$.

$\lambda=\frac{h}{mv}=\frac{6.63\times10^{-34}}{0.046\times30}=4.8\times10^{-34}m$

The wavelength of the golf ball is so small compared with its dimensions that we would not expect any wave aspects in its behavior using ordinary instruments.